# String pointers and strcpy

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcpy

Why does this program give segmentation fault

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
    ptr = "string";
    strcpy(ptr,"NewString");
}
```

while this does not

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(ptr,"String");
    ptr = "Newstring";
}
```

OR the similar program when one literal in the string is to be modified

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr = "string";
    ptr[1] = 's';
}
```

when this does not

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(ptr,"String");
    ptr[1] = 's';
}
```

Comment: In the 2nd example, the optimizer is free to eliminate the strcpy, since the next line replaces the value.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @stark :  the optimizer is free to eliminate the strcpy, can you please provide any link for further study and understanding

Answer (score 1):

All of above scenarios cause **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**.

For ease of explanation, let's call the four snippets as (I), (II), (III) and (IV), in order of appearance.

- So, in (I), `strcpy(ptr,"String");` is an attempt to write to non-writable memory (attempt to modification of string literal, put another way).
- In (II), `strcpy(ptr,"String");` causes memory overrun as the destination has lesser space than the source.
- In (III), `ptr[1] = 's';` is an attempt to modify (part of) string literal.
- In (IV), same as (II).

You cannot reasonify the outcome of a program causing UB. Segmentation fault is **one of the many possible side effects** of UB, **not the only one**.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @ThingyWotsit maybe someone lost their key, or .....

Comment: No, because the original version (containing only the first and last sentence) - while correct - really wasn't useful in any way. Now some content was added, but I ask myself, where the reason is to just spit out a sensess answer as fast as possible and then refining it step by step.

Comment: It looks like a homework dump anyway:(

Comment: @Ctx Well, it was an answer, useful or not, up to you. The outcome of UB is explained in the link...so it was self sufficient. A bit of polish never hurts. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh He asked, _why_ the program gives a segmentation fault. The response "it's UB" just explains, why this behaviour is standard compliant, but it is not the reason for the segv itself. You now start to provide a real answer, so I'll retract the DV. But I personally do not like useless, early answers, just to be the first to go...

Comment: @Sourav  attempt to write to non-writable memory, can you please explain it more. Where is this 'ptr' stored in memory ? Data section or Code section.

Comment: @Kranthi depends on the compiler, should be in read-only memory, for most of them. C only mandates that attempt to alter a string literal will cause UB.

Comment: Also what is the difference between assigning string literal to ptr and strcpy. What exactly happens in the compiler